# on either side of them

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, prepositional-phrases

*The boys walk through the crowds with junkie stuff being sold at stations **on either side of them**.*

I have got stuck in the above sentence. I am not sure to which noun the pronoun *them* is connected. Is it crowds, stations or boys?

Comment: OW, OW, I vote for "boys"!

Comment: Where did you find this phrase? - In the United States, the word _junkie_ usually means "person addicted to narcotics."  When I read _"junkie stuff being sold at stations,"_ I pictured booths full of needles, crack pipes and butane lighters.  If I were going for the meaning the author is (probably?) after, "low quality, low value," I would write "junky."  It is a much less common word;  I would probably use "trashy" instead.  That carries its own idiomatic baggage ("of low moral standards with regard to sexual activity"), but the "low quality, low value" meaning is also commonly used.

Comment: It is from my comic book South Park, including episodes Good times with weapons and Cartman gets an anal probe. The quotation is from the former one. Junkie stuff is in this comic a sort of firecrackers for children.

Comment: that would be *'junky'* stuff as @Adam said - **big** difference between 'cheap toys for children' & 'smokers' requisites for the discerning drug addict' ;)

Comment: The proofreader of the comic probably failed.

Answer (score 5):

The boys.

> **The boys walk through the crowds** *with junkie stuff being sold at stations on either side of them*.

I've emboldened the main clause, and italicized the subordinate clause.

The word *them* can only refer to the subject or one of the objects in this sentence:

1. The boys (subject)
2. The crowds (object)
3. The junkie stuff (object)

The station is not an object in this sentence because nothing is being acted upon it. So which of the above three choices is *them* referring to?

It can't be the junkie stuff, because that's what's located on either side of *them*.

It can't be the crowds because they were the object in the previous clause, not the subordinate clause.

So it has to be the boys.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is hard to parse because it is incorrectly punctuated.

Could *them* refer to the "junkie stuff" or "stations"? No, that makes no sense.

Could *them* refer to "the crowds"? It's logically unlikely, but that is what the punctuation leads you to conclude. There is no comma after *crowds*, so *with junkie stuff being sold at stations on either side of them*, at first interpretation, seems to modify *crowds*.

In contrast, consider a correctly punctuate sentence:

> The boys walk through the crowds, with junkie stuff being sold at stations on either side of them.

Now it is clearer that the second half of the sentence adds detail to the main clause in general.